# How do I access the the current annotation's class during "viewForAnnotation"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, callout

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"User"];
    UIImageView *myCustomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    MyPin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage;
}
```

I want to set the annotation's leftCalloutAccessoryView to a specific image I won't know until runtime. I have the specific image needed defined within each separate annotation created, but how do I access the specific annotation's class within this function so that I can set the myCustomImage accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[someClassHere class]]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I allow the user to input any picture they want from the internet, so I need to get the current pin's UIImage picture(which won't be known until run-time). So i don't think this will help.

Comment: Why can't you get the image from the annotation class if your custom annotation class stores it?

Comment: Well, I guess my question is, what is the syntax? Say my custom annotation class has the header file with "UIImage *Pic;" defined within the interface, how can I access "Pic" for the current annotation within this function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: So my custom annotation class has a "UIImage *Pic" that is different for every user. And I need to display this Pic in the callout "lefCalloutAccessoryView". I envision it would be something along the lines of... myCustomImage.image = currentAnnotation.Pic (where myCustomImage is a UIIMageView that I will assign to the "leftCalloutAccessoryView". But I'm not sure how the code would look in terms of gaining access to "Pic".

Answer (score 0):

Use this, and then you can use temp to access certain members of your class.

```
Pin *temp = (Pin *)annotation;
```